# Fira Sans font face not picking in firefox

Tags: wordpress, firefox, fonts

I am developing a webpage in wordpress. For the content of the page I am using Fira Sans Font family.

I have included the google fonts style sheet in head section as

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:400,500" rel="stylesheet">
```

Also, I tried importing the fonts in my css file as

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:400,500');

The fonts are working properly in chrome and IE but not in firefox. Firefox picks Arial font family.

Can some one help why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem in font if you're loading it from Google Fonts.

Change URL to: https://code.cdn.mozilla.net/fonts/fira.css and it will work.

By https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1100658 it was fixed a year ago, but you probably make no misstake if you change URL to mozilla CDN.